# Convert nested list into flat dataframe

Tags: r, list

lets say I have nested list and I want to convert it into flat data frame in R. look into picture for reference. SO what should I do ?

[Nested List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fE8z.jpg)

Comment: You may need `unnest`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the unlist command,

```
l.ex <- list(a = list(1:5, LETTERS[1:5]), b = "Z", c = NA)
unlist(l.ex, recursive = FALSE)
unlist(l.ex, recursive = TRUE)
```

Also look into as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, vectorOfUnlist))